# Refresh OAuth client token in a thread-safe way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, concurrency, thread-safety

My app is consuming an OAuth resource and, from time to time, an access token must be refreshed using its refresh token. To this end, I'm doing something like:

```
record = MyClientModel.find(...)
client = OAuthClient.new(record.access_token)

begin
  tries ||= 2
  client.do_something
rescue ExpiredOAuthToken => e
  new_access_token, new_refresh_token = 
    client.refresh_token(record.refresh_token)
  client.access_token = new_access_token
  record.access_token = new_access_token
  record.refresh_token = new_refresh_token
  record.save
  retry unless (tries -= 1).zero?
  raise e
end
```

This code is designed to be run simultaneously in web requests and in worker processes but, obviously, it is not thread-safe, e.g.:

1. `record.access_token` expires
2. Thread A encounters `ExpiredOAuthToken`
3. Thread A calls `#refresh_token`
4. Thread B encounters `ExpiredOAuthToken`
5. Thread B calls `#refresh_token` but fails because `record.refresh_token` is now invalid
6. Thread A persists new token
7. Thread A continues

I've never really had to think about thread safety before so I'm looking for suggestions on how I might go about improving this code.

Comment: Is this really two threads? It sounds like there are two separate processes (ie a controller and a worker).

Comment: Actually, @SunilD., you're absolutely correct, and this proves how little I've had to think about this in the past. How would you suggest I re-word my question?

Comment: I was just splitting hairs Your problem is about concurrency. In the end the solutions might be similar: use some sort of flag to track when a particular token refresh is under way.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently come across this issue - in my case, I am storing my access tokens in an ActiveRecord model, so I can use the ActiveRecord `with_lock` method (with MySQL / PostgreSQL).

```
# ...inside Authorization model instance methods
def refresh
  # do not allow more than one refresh to occur simultaneously
  with_lock do
    # if the token was just refreshed, return (there may be threads waiting on this token)
    return oauth_token if updated_at > 5.seconds.ago

    oauth = OmniAuth::Strategies::Custom.new(nil)
    token =
      OAuth2::AccessToken.new(
        oauth.client,
        oauth_token,
        refresh_token: oauth_refresh_token
      )

    new_token = token.refresh!
    return unless new_token

    update!(
      oauth_token: new_token.token,
      oauth_refresh_token: new_token.refresh_token,
      oauth_expires_at: Time.at(new_token.expires_at)
    ) && new_token.token
  end
end
```

When my threads encounter an expired token, they will all call `refresh`, but only the first `refresh` is executed, the other threads wait, and will immediately get the new token when it is updated.